# JavaScript function termination on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a function in JavaScript that makes cubes follow the mouse movement but I need to make them go back to their original position when I hover over a specific div and stop them moving as long as the mouse is inside of that div that. If I move the mouse inside that button the cube dosen't move but goes back to moving the moving after I get out of the button.

```js
function cubes() {
  $(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
      $(".cube1").attr("style", "transform: translateX(" + ax + "px) 
        translateY("+ay+"
          px)
        ");
      });
  };

  $(".button").hover(function() {
    $(".cube1").css({
      "transforme": "translate(0)"
    })
  });
```

```css
.button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Where are `ax` and `ay` coming from? When asking questions on Stack Overflow please make sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the `mousemove` event on `.button` and then use [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM to the document.

```js
function cubes() {
  $(document).on("mousemove", function(evnt) {
  
    let {clientX, clientY} = evnt;
      $(".cube1").css('transform', `translateX(${clientX}px) translateY(${clientY}px)`);
  });

  $(".button").on('mouseenter', function() {
    // when the mouse enters the button snap
    // cube1 back to its default position
    $(".cube1").css({
      "transform": "translate(0)"
    });
  });

  $(".button").on('mousemove', function(evnt) {
    // Capture the mousemove event on this element,
    // and stop propagation so the document does not receive
    // the mousemove event.
    evnt.stopPropagation();
  });
}

cubes();
```

```css
    .button {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: #96bdd9;
    }
    .cube1 {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background: #e1ecf4;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="cube1">Cube</div>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
```

A couple of things you might now be familiar with:

- I used a [`template literal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make the transform string a little more readable. Most modern browsers [support template literals](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals), the big exception is IE, but it is not what I would call a modern browser.
- I used [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to get the `clientX` and `clientY` values from the event object. Destrcturing is [supported by most browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring,_declarations), including IE 11.
- I used [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to declare my variable; even IE 11 supports let.

If you need to support older browsers, this stuff could be rewritten using ES5 instead.

Answer (score -1):

I don´t know it it´s an answer but you have a little typo here:

```
$(".cube1").css({"transform":"translate(0)"})
```

Comment: thanks but it.s not the solution even that get it back to original position but keeps move according to mouse coordinate